# Testing for color and width?

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to javascript and I have a question. I'm currently trying to make a loading bar change color and reset after it has reached 100%, but the main issue is, or at least I think my if statement is invalid. Anyway to test for color and width of an element? Thanks.

```
        function upg_01() {
    if (cash >= priceUpg_01) {
    var width = 0;
    width = width + 20;
    a.style.width = width + '%';
    priceUpg_01 = priceUpg_01 * 10;
    multiplier_01 = multiplier_01 * 3;
  }
 if (document.getElementById('upg_01c').style.color === "green" && 
document.getElementById('upg_01c') === 100 + '%') {
    document.getElementById('upg_01c').style.color = "yellow";
    document.getElementById('upg_01c').style.width = 0 + '%';
 }
```

Comment: keep in mind i have fixed the single "=" and have replaced them with === inside the if statements...

Comment: what kind of element is upg_01c ?

Comment: Ok, I have fixed it, i needed to put "" around the color types, but still it doesn't seem to execute the function at all? Anything you can do about that, Doug?

Comment: Next question: How are you calling the upg_01 function? JS will just read it once and move on.  This is not actively "listening" to changes.

Comment: And when in doubt about testing values, always drop the test condition into a console (or alert) -- just so you know what the browser returns (for example, if you wanted to test document.getElementById('upg_01c').style.color )

Comment: I have edited the code, I am calling it through a onclick inside a div, so when it clicks off again it should trigger the second if in that function. It now is only adding 20% once and will not do it again after being clicked twice.

Comment: Looks like you need something like state management -- something outside of this function that could track your current progress.  As it is now it will always set the width to 20% (and not hit that second if) because the width is being declared as such.

Comment: well, when clicked again it should add 20, (width = width + 20;) and effectively change the width

Comment: ok i have fixed it now, it seems as if the local var, width, is required to be outside of the function... but let me ask you this now, how do i testfor the  width and color now. I still dont really know how or atleast it isnt functioning

Comment: I'm going to to change the if statements to a var based approach...

Comment: `document.getElementById('upg_01c').style.width` will return the current width of your bar -- so you can do something like `var width = document.getElementById('upg_01c').style.width` but be sure to do something like `parseInt()` (to strip the percentile character)  and be sure to assign it back to the element to update it.

Comment: That is what I have done, thank you for all the help!

Comment: if you're still testing for the color, be sure to run that test on as many browsers as possible -- some may report back the hex code rather than the plain text description (just a nice sanity check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const timer = setInterval( () => {
  // select the progress bar element
  const progressBar = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
  // get the innerHTML of the progess bar
  // doubling as our progress state/value
  let progress = parseInt( progressBar.innerHTML );
  // arbitrary addition/growth of the progress
  progress += 3;
  // check if progress has met or exceeded 100%
  if( progress >= 100 ){
    // this is just for the setInterval to stop it 
    // from continually executing
    clearInterval( timer );
    // add a new class to the progress bar (keeping
    // the CSS separate from the JavaScript -- there's
    // a lot of opinions on this, do what you feel
    // comfortable with
    progressBar.className = 'yellow';
  }
  // Update the progress value inside the progress
  // bar
  progressBar.innerHTML = progress;
  // Update the width of the progress bar by setting
  // the css style value
  progressBar.style.width = progress + '%';
// timed loop that will trigger every 100 miliseconds
}, 100 );
```

```css
#progress-bar{
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 0px;
  width: 0%; height: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
  #progress-bar.yellow{ background-color: yellow; }
#loader-wrapper{
  padding: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="loader-wrapper">
  <div id="progress-bar">0</div>
</div>
```